# how do I return multiple rows with the same min or max value in R ?? (right now it only picks one)

Tags: r, group-by, minimum

Can someone please help me to return more than one row with the same minimum value.

I have dataset with the columns:

```
ID   TEST_TYPE  TEST_NUMBER
```

and I need to return the maximum test number and the minimum test number for each ID. The problem is, there are lots of different tests and a singular ID can have test type a and b which are both performed 1 time. When I try to get the minimum value for the ID I get only test a.

I want to get duplicated rows of the same ID that matches the minimum TEST_NUMBER, with the different TEST_TYPE

to return:

```
ID    TEST_TYPE   TEST_NUMBER
876      a             1
876      b             1
```

I am currently using the following code but it is only giving me one match per ID and not all matches with duplicate ID:

```
Q_TEST <- Q_TEST %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.min(TEST_NUMBER))
```

please help

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide some data? It would be easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Try: `which(TEST_NUMBER == min(TEST_NUMBER))`

Comment: `slice_min(TEST_NUMBER)` should give you your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Q_TEST <- Q_TEST %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(TEST_NUMBER == min(TEST_NUMBER))
```

The equality filter condition will hold for all the minimum values in each group.